# Is java:openjdk-8-jre an offical docker image

Tags: docker

I could pull `java:openjdk-8-jre` with `docker pull java:openjdk-8-jre` command. But I **can't find it out** in https://hub.docker.com/. I can't find a page for `java` like other official images, e.g. `openjdk`. When I went to `https://hub.docker.com/_/java`, it was redirected to `https://hub.docker.com/_/openjdk`. So I guess it's renamed with `openjdk`. Where can I find the related infos about `java:openjdk-8-jre` in official docker hub.

Answer (score 0):

As of the are two more or less official java distributions - the OracleJDK and OpenJDK (there are as well some derivatives of OpenJDK). Thus you either pull from [https://hub.docker.com/*/oracle-jdk*](https://hub.docker.com/_/oracle-jdk) or [https://hub.docker.com//openjdk](https://hub.docker.com/_/openjdk). The *java:openjdk-8-jre* is pre-split version on official repo and shouldn't e use as is outdated:

```
$ docker inspect --format='{{index .Created}}'  java:openjdk-8-jre
2017-01-17T00:53:21.516522468Z

$ docker inspect --format='{{index .Created}}'  openjdk:8-jre
2020-05-15T21:05:09.719485985Z
```

**Note**: To use Oracle JDK requires subscription.